# Python, Gtk+ deployment for Windows OS (Multiplatform)

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, glade

Is it possible to write GUI application using Python and GTK+ (GTK 3), and then to distribute that application on different OS (primarily Windows) ? Can it work on different OS.

Comment: ummm python code can be run an any system that has python... if you want to create a binary executable you will need to create it on the OS you are targeting or find an appropriate cross-compiler(not sure there are any... certainly none that are easy to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to compile and distribute ? yes, you can create .exe s. If you are using Win, then you can use pyinstaller. Worked for me. But certainly, had some issues with some libraries, but newer versions may support them, evenly. If not, py2exe is one such another. Try them.

pyinstaller -- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
py2exe -- http://www.py2exe.org/